# python3 textwrap unexpected output on json format?

Tags: json, python-3.x, word-wrap

```
>>> a = '{"key1": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "key2": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"}'
>>> len(a)
64
>>> textwrap.wrap(a, 32, drop_whitespace=False)
['{"key1": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", ', '"key2": ', '"bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"}']
```

I was expecting

```
['{"key1": "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa", "k', 'ey2": "bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb"}']
```

I'am missing something ?

Comment: What is the output you get then ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expectation is wrong, according to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.wrap):

> Wraps the single paragraph in text (a string) so every line is at most width characters long. Returns a list of output lines, without final newlines.
>   [...]
>   **Text is preferably wrapped on whitespaces** and right after the hyphens in hyphenated words; only then will long words be broken if necessary, unless `TextWrapper.break_long_words` is set to false.

Your expected output is literally broken off after 32 characters, whereas the actual output is split into segments of 30, 8, and 27 characters long – broken only on the whitespace characters in the original string.

The second segment is much shorter than the others because the first string plus this next non-whitespace run `"key2":` is longer than 32 characters, and this short run plus the *next* phrase is *also* longer than 32 characters. Only when there is absolutely no possibility to break on a space or hyphen, a break in the middle of a non-whitespace run will occur.